# Exception "System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed" after unsuccessfully NTAccount.Translate

Tags: windows, security, .net-core

I have this problem on a asp.net website, but it should be general for .Net Core on windows computer.

If I try to translate an nonexistent Domain, I’ll get an exception, it’s OK, but then, all next calls with correct domain name throw an exception also "System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed".

I'm asking about some workaround, because name translation does ‘not work until restart of application.

---

This behavior can be reproduced with

- Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0
- System.Security.Principal.Windows 4.5.1

---

```
class Program
{
    static string Translate(string gName)
    {
        try
        {
            var nt = new NTAccount(gName);
            if (nt.IsValidTargetType(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)))
            {
                var si = (SecurityIdentifier)(nt).Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
                return si.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            Console.Write(ex.ToString()+"\n\n");                
        }
        return "";
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var si= new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);
        var na = si.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
        var knownName = na.ToString();
        foreach (var aName in new[] {  knownName,
                                       @"DOMAIN_NOT_ESISTS\Benutzer",
                                       knownName  })
        {
            Console.WriteLine(aName);
            Console.WriteLine(Translate(aName));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your code in a casual test, with versions you show, I cannot reproduce this, FWIW.

Comment: a problem seems to appear only together with broken connection to domain controller.
If a connection OK, the Program behaves as expected:

If I take off a computer from a net, I’ll get an exception for a valid account also and is still to throw exception until a restart of program. For an web application its critical, it couldn’t be restarted anytime.

Thanks for advice.